# RubyMine new app issue: activesupport requires Ruby version >= 2.2.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubymine

I'm trying to create a new Rails application in RubyMine but running into the following error.

> **Failed to Install Gems**
>
> Following gems were not installed: rails
> (5.0.0): Error installing rails: activesupport requires Ruby version
> = 2.2.2

Selecting a `Rails Version` is mandatory, but there are no version listed except `Install rails gems`.

[image]

After selecting a version of Rails and clicking install, it fails with the above error.

This seems strange because if I open the terminal outside RubyMine and run `ruby -v`, it shows,

```
ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-darwin13]
```

This is my first time creating a new application on my desktop (instead of cloud IDE) so I'm kind of lost.

Could this be an issue related to RVM? Or can anyone advise how I might be able to troubleshoot this?

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/ruby/2016.1/configuring-ruby-sdk.html should be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wanted to write this up for anyone else that might get stuck here (thanks for the link Prakash).

1. Click `configure` in first window upon opening RM.
2. Click `Languages and frameworks`
3. Click `Ruby SDK and gems`
4. Click `RVM: ruby-2.3.0` (think you will need to install this on your mac first)
5. Click green checkmark at bottom of list which shows ruby versions
6. Now create a new project

*Note: Above allowed me to at least create a new Rails project. But I haven't yet taken it to the point of a fully functional app.*